# How do I make a map like this?

Tags: 3d-view

I just saw this river Basin map in Twitter and thought to replicate the work in another catchment I am having. I have all the associated files such as dem, drainage with me but I don't know the steps in blender. [image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67142/cycles-material-with-color-based-on-height-and-backside-in-different-colors/67145#67145 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5491/how-do-i-colour-a-3d-terrain-based-on-its-height and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91648/is-there-another-way-to-make-a-coloured-topography/91653#91653

Comment: Thanks but first link is related but don't have any information related to the detailed hillshade and colour ramp used. Also nothing about the plane too.

Comment: The DEM you can use as height map. Then use the height to assign colors based on the height (detailed on the links on the second comment), the colors you use are up to you. If that doesn't help please [edit] your question and specify what kind of information you are in need of.

Comment: Ok. I will go through the links and test it on my own and update the question.